# A "newspaper in the photo" but for audio? Audible hash/signature/password/watermark for timestamp? What (live?) audio channel validates Proof of Time?

Tags: recording, timecode, time, realtime, forensics

## TL;Dr: Is recording by livestreaming your own audio 24/7 the securest method as an individual, to get a "newspaper in the photo" audio proof?

(Withstanding latency...)

Is there any better social sound tracking system?

#### **Theoretical Examples:**

*We are not talking about Havana Syndrome or tinnitus issues.*

1. My long-term parent er landlord screamed and or banged pots and pans by my room from 3h to 7h (3AM to 7AM), prove it with just sound bites?
2. At exactly 03h07, a heavy machinery WM.com dumpster truck backs in ten (10) meters away, starts revving their engine like a racecar and running their forklift at extremely high decibels, reverberations physically shaking me and my home (and my neighbors, does that matter?). How do I prove, with just the sound/audio signature recorded from my smartphone, that I was woken by that (high-decibel) at the brink of dawn 3:07AM?

Provability helped by radio/tv news in background (reruns/repeats?)?  What is suggested, if I need to be able to prove that a sound happened and (is clockable as proof of) at a certain exact time.

Is there an audio channel that works best as a timestamp? If I change to a radio channel and the commercial is the same as before, that's *not as good* for `proof of timestamp`?

**Any self-recorded audio would be the same example, can you tell me exactly what second a word was said in Universal Standard Time for each word?**

My personal angle, to use me as just one example, was from asking by search engine speaking "best live audio stream (is radio/TV news?) to timestamp audio?" I meant 'What is the suggested method for timestamping/dating the audio recording I just made'. I mean **you have to trust the time written by me/you** the User) and https://steemit.com/csychology/@scribe/qd9npv my "blockchain proof" to prove my experience from seconds ago I have to transcribe that it happened at that time, trust that my audio recorder timestamp is accurate, and have you trust me?

Well because of technological reasons, partly done to follow professional workflow standards, posting process from [www.AudioShip.io](http://www.AudioShip.io) to [www.YouTube.com](http://www.YouTube.com) took/delayed hours for, again, mainly technology reasons, seemingly another Digital Divide beyond what would be the value a "newspaper in the photo" is, for there is not an equivalent for audio. I was trying AudioShip in comparison to YouTube, thinking there would be greater timestamp validity in some viewable metadata, but there is not any real `proof of time`.

Comparatively, we can send a timestampable sexting message with greater proofing than a single word we say with an audible mouth [not to mention, the scroll feature to track linear sound is emotionally tolling (literally an emotional experience to rehear, a page of text does not bite like an hour of audio equivalently, and the evidence process is generally manually intensive in comparison.

I am worried about how audio is transient, asking myself if audio is not enough proof for the legal system, if I did not activate a radio or TV with some verifiable `time signature`: '`I know that sound happened at that time because I heard the radio anchor say that the first time then, that was that issue's first ever word, very first words`'.

I am not asking [Recognition of timing information by sound device](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/39477/recognition-of-timing-information-by-sound-device/39491#39491) about if my sound recorder knows what min/sec I am at in the tracking bar. The issue is proving as a matter of fact that what the "sound device" thinks is the time is not the (painfully sadly for record-keeping standards if) only proof we have to ask for. Why should I (scientifically, evidentiarily) trust my/your tape recorder said that cursed/claimed/alleged/accused/"documented" hexspeak of a timestamp?

I am asking how to mechanically or socially make sure for myself and others that that sound happened at that time, is that a security feature, do any sound recorders record timestamps.

of pending audio streams before you're able to save fully to Google Drive, in my test case?

Do we need a radio frequency AM/FM/HAM that has, a voice counting a clock every second?, a newscast that never has commercials or repeating sections?, or a constantly changing rhythym and sound or whatever, to 100% know (like **a password for sound itself (audible timestamp hash/signature/password/watermark)**, maybe a blockchain for sound itself), **can we verify that sound definitely happened at that time the sound happened**, that sound means that timedatestamp?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131541/discussion-on-question-by-prosody-gabe-vereable-context-a-newspaper-in-the-phot).

Comment: This still sounds more like forensics than sound design to me.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a forensics question, the answer to which is is the ENF signal ([Electrical Network Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_network_frequency_analysis)) which is used in forensics to locate certain associated acoustic and electrical signals in time for forensic purposes

ENF is a technique commonly used in audio forensics. It requires analysts to have recorded ENF signals over a long period of time.

Comment: I would comment that your idea is (just currently?) cost prohibitive but that does not change the fact it is a good idea. If that's the only way, I find that astounding. I wonder if there will be efforts to make the "time domain"/timestamp analysis ability common so normal people can establish extremely credible audio recordings. (So normal people who need that kind of credible proof/evidence/assessment are stuck technologically til the gov't open sources the ability of law enforcement to use ENF time domain/timestamp analysis, but for giving personal protection and security if not integrity?)

Answer (score 2):

How about embedding a [smart contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract) into the audio using [digital watermarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking)?

Essentially, a trusted encrypted ledger entry could embed the date (or any particular information) such that later on you could retrieve the value and compare it against what is in the ledger.

Don't know if that's a thing, but it sounds like it could work.

Comment: A quick Google found some audio watermarking tools at https://audiowatermarking.info/awt1_main.php.

Comment: I was thinking the process maybe as a https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/48548/19675 "ENF blockchain"(?), an Electrical Network Frequency backed by the blockchain, where the sound (of a single word at a certain time, for example) is recorded with an analyzable audio timestamp then hashed on chain. (I did not think to call the idea ~"smart contract audio watermarking". That nearly implies the same sort of idea I was trying to express by saying the word "blockchain" and "audio" together, but seems for Digital Rights Management mainly, interestingly not sold as specific Audio Timestamp Products.)